# MVC 5 thoughts on implementing a back to calling page feature

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement some functionality so that when a user makes a change to an item - it will redirect them back to the calling page.

This is because there may be multiple pages which point to an edit function.

ie. you could go to the Edit Customer from the Customer List or from say a Order for -> Edit Customer link.

When they have made the change I want to return to the page they came from.

I'm thinking I have will have to send appropriate info to the view using a ViewModel and then when the change action Create/Delete/Update occurs read these values in use them for a redirectToAction.

Trying to get any more thoughts on the simplest way to achieve this and whether I am overcomplicating my train of thought on how to implement this.

Comment: You could either pass the current URL in the request to the Edit page.  Or within the Edit action, check the `Request.UrlReferrer`.

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach to this is to use a query string for the return URL. So in your link you would have:

```
<a href="/customer/1234/edit?return_url=/order/1234">Edit Customer</a>
```

Obviously, encoding the `/order/1234` part of the url would be advised. Then, in your /customer/1234/edit action, you would check for the existence of the "return_url" query string parameter, and if it exists, then redirect back to the specified URL.